# Ansible 2.4 check for match "word" in output

Tags: regex, ansible

I would like to use `ansible` to check if a package name exist in an output of a command. if not exist do something.

for example :
I'm looking for the package "zip" but the problem is that it return "gzip" "zip" "unzip" and I'm looking to find only "zip" ,how to do it in a when condition

How can I use regex to match the `{{ item.name }}` exactly and not words that contains part of `{{ item.name }}`

```
 - name: Check if Package is installed
      shell: dpkg-query -f '${binary:Package}\n' -W
      register: is_installed

    - name: Install apt dependencies
      apt:
        name: "{{item.name}}{{item.version}}"
        state: present
        allow_unauthenticated: yes
        force: yes
      with_items:
        - { name: 'python2.7', version: '' }
        - { name: 'ruby', version: '' }
        - { name: 'postgresql-9.5', version: '' }
        - { name: 'postgresql-contrib-9.5', version: '' }
        - { name: 'libpq-dev', version: '' }
        - { name: 'nodejs', version: '=9.*' }
        - { name: 'python-setuptools', version: '' }
        - { name: 'python-pip', version: '' }
        - { name: 'python-pkg-resources', version: '' }
        - { name: 'sshpass', version: '' }
        - { name: 'zip', version: '' }
        - { name: 'mongodb-org', version: '=4.0.0' }
        - { name: 'libfontconfig', version: '' }
        - { name: 'ntp', version: '' }
        - { name: 'fio', version: '' }
      when: not "{{item.name}}" in is_installed.stdout
```

Comment: Could you add a brief example of the format of the output in `is_installed.stdout` to your question?

Comment: its return a list of all the packages installed in the system :
tasksel-data
tcpd
tcpdump
telnet
time
tmux
tzdata
ubuntu-keyring
ubuntu-minimal
ubuntu-release-upgrader-core
ubuntu-standard
ucf
udev
ufw
unattended-upgrades
unzip
update-manager-core
update-notifier-common
upstart
ureadahead
usbutils
util-linux
uuid-runtime
vim
vim-common
vim-runtime
vim-tiny
w3m
watershed
wget
whiptail
wireless-regdb
wireless-tools
wpasupplicant
xauth
xkb-data
xml-core
xz-utils
zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am only partially able to test as don't have a Debian based machine in front of me.

You didn't update your Q to show the exact format of the output, so I am not sure if the command is outputting all the packages on a single line, or is outputting one per line.

If one per line, try this:

```
- name: Install apt dependencies
  apt:
    name: "{{item.name}}{{item.version}}"
    state: present
    allow_unauthenticated: yes
    force: yes
  with_items:
    - { name: 'python2.7', version: '' }
    - { name: 'ruby', version: '' }
  when: not (is_installed.stdout_lines| map('regex_search', '^' + item.name + '$') | select('string') | list | length)
```

If on multiple lines, then `is_installed.stdout_lines` will be a list, with one package per item. Therefore we search the list for exact matches, and output the total count of matches. >0 = `true`.

If all on the same line, then try this instead:

```
- name: Install apt dependencies
  apt:
    name: "{{item.name}}{{item.version}}"
    state: present
    allow_unauthenticated: yes
    force: yes
  with_items:
    - { name: 'python2.7', version: '' }
    - { name: 'ruby', version: '' }
  when: not (is_installed.stdout | search('(^| )' + item.name + '( |$)')
```

In this case, we need to search for the `name` either at the beginning of the line or preceded by a space, and then followed by a space or the end of the line, for an exact match.

Comment: @clocworknet but now i have a new problem, if im changing the version of the package for example : from mongodb-org 4.0.0 to mongodb-org 5.0.0 when i run the playbook it skipping the task because it check if mongodb-org installed and not the version... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your regex like below

```
 when: not (?<![\w\d]){{item.name}}(?![\w\d]) in is_installed.stdout
```

Comment: dont think i can use it it doesnt work:      [WARNING]: when statements should not include jinja2 templating delimiters such as {{ }} or {% %}. Found: not "(?<![\w\d])({{item.name}})(?![\w\d])" in is_installed.stdout